# Trying to put a 2010 Chevy cobalt 2.2 motor in a 2006 HHR

Tags: chevrolet, cobalt, hhr

Everything seems to line up except the head or cams are different so you would think change the wiring harnesses but the plug that goes in the fuse box so is there a fix

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If I can ask ... what is a "Jr"?

Comment: Hhr sorry for the typo

Comment: The hhr had a cam adjuster the Cobalt has the 2 solenoid and cam sensor s